# state inside a onKeyDown's function doesn't update instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function to read the keyboard delete event key:

```
const handleTextDel = (event) => {
    let key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ){
      setMyState(2)
    }
}
```

the input looks like this:

```
           <input 
            type="text" 
            value={myInputValue} 
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleTextDel(e)}
          />
```

then I have another dom element like so:

```
<div>{myState}</div>
```

why the `myState` value becomes `2` only at the second press of the delete key?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you can use the `useEffect` hook to update the state after the batch has been applied.

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

const handleTextDel = (event) => {
  let key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
    setMyState(2);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  // This code will run after the batch has been applied
  console.log("myState updated:", myState);
}, [myState]);

return (
  <div>
    <input type="text" value={myInputValue} onKeyDown={handleTextDel} />
    <div>{myState}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: it looks more like a cheat than a proper way of doing but absurdly enough by adding a console.log as you did in a useEffect dedicated to that state, makes in fact update it correctly in the dom without delay

Comment: By using the useEffect hook with the myState dependency, you can log the updated myState value after it has been applied. This way, you can verify that the state is updating as expected. if my answer solved your issues, can you mark it as accepted ? thank you :)